# How does LINQ contains work

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I understand how to use LINQ so the syntax is not important here. How exactly does LINQ interpenetrate "contains" and what is going on in the background? I understand that it finds all the elements that have the word you are looking for but will it find a result with multiple words that are not all contained? For example I have a row in a database for a name and if i use contains will I be able to find my person with

```
Contains("James Bar")
```

If the real name is James foo Bar

Or does the query simply look for

```
where name like '%James bar%'
```

and not return the result

Comment: Are you talking about `string.Contains`?  If so, then yes it would roughly be translated to a like with precent wildcards before and after the passed in string.

Comment: This depends on the underlying LINQ provider. Are you using LINQ to SQL?

Comment: I guess it would be string.Contains so that makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here we go --- check it out via [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,ef82268cfee756fe):   Contains calls IndexOf with a greater equal comparison and that calls an overloaded IndexOf method. hth

```
        [Pure]
        public bool Contains( string value ) {
             return ( IndexOf(value, StringComparison.Ordinal) >=0 );
        }

        [Pure]
        public int IndexOf(String value, StringComparison comparisonType) {
            return IndexOf(value, 0, this.Length, comparisonType);
        }

        [Pure]
        [System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]
        public int IndexOf(String value, int startIndex, int count, StringComparison comparisonType) {
            // Validate inputs
            if (value == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

            if (startIndex < 0 || startIndex > this.Length)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("startIndex", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_Index"));

            if (count < 0 || startIndex > this.Length - count)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("count", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_Count"));
            Contract.EndContractBlock();

            switch (comparisonType) {
                case StringComparison.CurrentCulture:
                    return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(this, value, startIndex, count, CompareOptions.None);

                case StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase:
                    return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(this, value, startIndex, count, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase);

                case StringComparison.InvariantCulture:
                    return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(this, value, startIndex, count, CompareOptions.None);

                case StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase:
                    return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(this, value, startIndex, count, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase);

                case StringComparison.Ordinal:
                    return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(this, value, startIndex, count, CompareOptions.Ordinal);

                case StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase:
                    if (value.IsAscii() && this.IsAscii())
                        return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(this, value, startIndex, count, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    else
                        return TextInfo.IndexOfStringOrdinalIgnoreCase(this, value, startIndex, count);

                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("NotSupported_StringComparison"), "comparisonType");
            }  
        }
```